# How in symfony, create new entity in second database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a problem. I was able to configure symfony to connect to two databases.

config.yml:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            customer:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host2%'
                port:     '%database_port2%'
                dbname:   '%database_name2%'
                user:     '%database_user2%'
                password: '%database_password2%'
                charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~

            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:  ~
```

And here my question appears.
How create new entity in second database?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this into a controller:

```
$customerEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer');
```

or this:

```
$customerEm = $this->get('doctrine.orm.customer_entity_manager');
```

and then:

```
$yourEntity = new YourEntity();
$customerEm->persist(yourEntity);
$customerEm->flush();
```

Comment: you can create a symfony command and change entity manager inside it @Andersi

Comment: For the Doctrine commands I'm pretty sure you could add `--em=customer` to specify the customer entity manager.